# Code First POCO Design

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm creating a database using entity framework code first and I'm having some issues with the database/POCO design. My problem is with inheritance.

My system has two main user roles Lecturer and Student. I have a base User class which contains Id, Logon, Role (identifying them as either lecturer or student), Forename and Surname. If the user is a Lecturer then they also have a Tags Property (relationship) associated with them. If the user is a Student then they have a year and a degree type property.

Both types of users can create projects. A project has a proposer. What i want is to be able to get the Lecturer or Student type back from Project.Proposer but i can't seem to do that. I'm also not sure if Project.Proposer should be of type User  (the base class) in the project class, whether i can use a interface (with code first) or what.

I would appreciate any guidance or ideas people could give me, I've tried many variations but none seem to give me the desired result. Note: I am trying to avoid having a user class that has redundant data so i don't want the user class to contain the fields for lecturers and students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way todo this is properly in EF4 CodeFirst is to have a `Proposer` property of type `User` on the project.

After retrieving the project the Proposer will have the correct type, but the value will be boxed as `User`. In order to figure out what actual the actual type is you can use the `is` keyword like this:

```
// project is a Project instance    
if (project.Proposer is Lecturer)
{
   // do something
} else if (project.Proposer is Student)
{
   // do something else
}
```

This is the datastructure I would suggest:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public abstract class User 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }        
    public string Surename { get; set; }
}

public class Lecturer : User
{
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Forename { get; set; }
}


public class Student : User
{
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Forename { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public User Proposer { get; set; }
}
```

There are other ways to structure this, like introducing a hierachy for the projects by using classes like `LecturerProject` `StudentProject` and move the `Proposer` with the correct type into the those classes, but this is not recommended. Since you will always have to handle these project classes separately. For example when retrieving the name of the project and it's proposer. Since the base project class does not have a proposer property anymore you need to have the same query twice. I hope I could illustrate the issues that arise when using this approach.

---

The next question you need to ask yourself is, do you care how the data is saved in the db? SInce there are 3 ways of doing this for classes with inheritance:

- [Table per Hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)
- [Table per Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)
- [Table per Concrete class](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

One word of advice. If you are not planning on storing millions of records, don't mind how it is actually stored in the db. `Table per Hierarchy` is by far the easiest to use, especially in the beginning, also it's the default.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Had to have lecturer project and student project anyway (again a base class and different sub classes) as they have different fields. Thanks for the links about different inheritance, a interesting read and it's good to know how that stuff works. As well as the is mechanism, I've been using the entity framework OfType<T> a lot as well. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to have a User class as the proposer, How about having a property like **ProposedUserId**, with that id, you can query the User class check what the users role is, and then get the necessary details from either the Lecture or Student table